# How can I compare two variable in onPress?

Tags: react-native, comparison

I am trying to create a changing pin screen and i was failed in comparing two variable that getting from the user (new pin and comfirm pin). The error show me that "this.state.newpin" is an undefined object.

```
class SettingScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    oldpin: '000000',
    newpin: '',
    secpin: ''
}


  onPressButton(){
    if( this.state.newpin == this.state.secpin){
            ToastAndroid.show("Password Changed", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
            this.setState({ oldpin : this.state.newpin})
       }
       else {
            ToastAndroid.show("Password Unmatched", ToastAndroid.SHORT);
       }
    }

  handleNewPin = (text) => {
         this.setState({ newpin: text })
    }

  handleSecPin = (text) => {
         this.setState({ secpin: text })
     }

...

<TextInput onChangeText = {this.handleNewPin} />
<TextInput onChangeText = {this.handleSecPin} />

<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPressButton}>
    <Text> Change Password </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I can get the output for "this.state.newpin" and "this.state.secpin" from user.
I just failed in the comparing statement ( OnPressButton()).

I am new in React-Native.

Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to bind your `onPressButton()`func. in the constructor with this. and move your state to constructor like this;

```
class SettingScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            oldpin: '000000',
            newpin: '',
            secpin: ''
        };
        this.onPressButton = this.onPressButton.bind(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed the code but the error still occurs at "onPressButton()"

Comment: you need to bind all handle functions. We must bind our functions which contain setState  for accesing this.setState

Comment: Did you mean "handleNewPin" and "handleOldPin"?

Comment: this.handleNewPin = this.handleNewPin.bind(this);
    this.handleSecPin = this.handleSecPin.bind(this);

Comment: Since they are arrow functions they don't need to be bound. So the problem is just the onPress. You can bind like @sdkcy did in this answer, or you can make it an arrow functon like the others

Comment: I've just created an [example snack](https://snack.expo.io/@milore/thankful-waffle). Take a look

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working now. Thank for helping.